# Overloaded extension methods works locally, but not on build server

Tags: c#

I have the following extension methods in my project:

```
public static void AddToDataTable<T>(this T instance, DataTable table) where T : IDatabaseObject
{
   DataRow row = table.NewRow();
   instance.PopulateRow(row);
   table.Rows.Add(row);
   //return row;
}

public static void AddToDataTable<T>(this ICollection<T> instances, DataTable table) where T : IDatabaseObject
{
   foreach (var instance in instances)
      instance.AddToDataTable(table);
}
```

I then call these functions in different places like this:

```
// Article is just a single item
articlePublishingInfo.Article.AddToDataTable(articleTable);
```

And also like this:

```
List<ArticlePagesDBO> articlePages = BuildAdditionalPageRelations(pagePublishing, articlePageInfo, pageData);
articlePages.AddToDataTable(dt);
```

This all works fine when compiling locally, but the build server spits out a compilation error saying

> The type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Vitec.Core.Web.Utilities.Data.DataObjects.CM.ArticlePagesDBO>'
> cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
> 'DatabaseObjectExtensions.AddToDataTable(T, DataTable)'. There is
> no implicit reference conversion from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Vitec.Core.Web.Utilities.Data.DataObjects.CM.ArticlePagesDBO>'
> to 'Vitec.Core.Web.Utilities.Data.IDatabaseObject'.

And it's like.. yeah, that seems about right, a `List<T>` is not the same as `T`. But why doesn't the build server find the overloaded version of the extension method? Any ideas? The extension method is defined in a different binary from where the calls are, and the name spaces of both types in the error message are correct.

If I rename the second method to something else, like AddAllToDataTable, then it works. But I kind of want to know why the overload fails, and what could be causing it. Originally the build server built the project using VS2015, but changing it to the same as my local environment, VS2019 did not help.

Comment: Probalby `IDatabaseObject` is defined in another binary and they are conflicting.

Comment: There is no other interface named that in any of the other project in the solution, nor in any of the dependencies, at least not the ones we're developing.

Comment: Your method is defined in the different binary. That’s it. Checksum the one you run locally and the remote one, I bet you gonna get different hashes.

Comment: How would I go about doing that at compile time, since it's a compilation error?

Comment: I also tried renaming IDatabaseObject, and that didn't help.

Comment: Take __binary__ file, physical *dll, and compute it's checksum. The one you got locally probably will yield different hash from the one you'll get on the remote binary, that ends up with exception.

Answer (score 0):

I went back through the logs, and realized that while the build job on the server was set to run Visual Studio 2019, it wasn't actually installed on the server, and the build reverted back to Visual Studio 2015 with a warning.

After installing VS2019 on the server, the build goes through, so I assume it was a problem with the C# version, perhaps overloading extension methods in the way I was doing was incompatible with VS2015.